# Putting try inside for gives IndentationError

Tags: python, indentation

I wonder why a simple 3 line code is popping this error. I've checked that the indentation is proper. I want to put some statements under `try` block immediately after the body of `for` begins.

Here's the code:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    try:
        print i
```

Sample run:

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs % python test.py
  File "test.py", line 4

                   ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

But if remove that `try` from the code, it works perfectly. I know that `except` is not mandatory after a `try` but I tried putting it too. It simply doesn't work. Can someone explain what's going on? I'm using Python 2.7.13 on Linux, in case it matters.

Comment: convert all indentation to spaces

Comment: You're probably mixing tabs and spaces. Use spaces always.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I've made sure that all the indentations are tabs.

Comment: @7_R3X: don't use tabs, use spaces.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming

Comment: " I know that except is not mandatory after a try but I tried putting it too." - **yes, it is**. That's the issue. Please see the linked duplicate. "It simply doesn't work." Then you did something else wrong; but we can't possibly diagnose that without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,
    for i in range(1, 10) :
        print ("before i",i)
        try :
            ("After i",i)
            print(i)
        except :
            print("At except")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use except. That code won't work. When something bad happens it is always good to know what actually happened whether it's a 3 lines of code or 3000 lines of code.

```
import sys

for i in range(1, 10):
    try:        
        print i
    except NameError : 
        print ('NameError detected.')
    except:
        a = sys.exc_info() # Info about unknown error that caused exception.       
        print a
```